# Вылет приложения при работе с Intent и ImageView

Tags: android

При нажатии на кнопку создаёт `Intent` на стандартное приложение Камера, делает снимок и сохраняет его в `ImageView`. При сохранении фотографии в `ImageLayout` во второй раз после запуска- приложение вылетает

```
public class FullscreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final int CAMERA_RESULT = 0;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    Button btnTakePhoto;
    Bundle bundle;

    private static int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;
    private Uri mOutputFileUri;
    TextView textView;
    /**
     * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
     * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
     */
    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

    /**
     * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
     * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
     */
    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

    /**
     * Some older devices needs a small delay between UI widget updates
     * and a change of the status and navigation bar.
     */
    private static final int UI_ANIMATION_DELAY = 300;
    private final Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    private View mContentView;
    private final Runnable mHidePart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Delayed removal of status and navigation bar

            // Note that some of these constants are new as of API 16 (Jelly Bean)
            // and API 19 (KitKat). It is safe to use them, as they are inlined
            // at compile-time and do nothing on earlier devices.
            mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        }
    };
    private View mControlsView, mControlsView1;
    private final Runnable mShowPart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Delayed display of UI elements
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            if (actionBar != null) {
                actionBar.show();
            }
            mControlsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mControlsView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };
    private boolean mVisible;
    private final Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            hide();
        }
    };
    /**
     * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
     * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
     * while interacting with activity UI.
     */
    private final View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (AUTO_HIDE) {
                delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
            }
            return false;
       }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
        bundle = savedInstanceState;
        mVisible = true;
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        mControlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
        mControlsView1 = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls1);
        mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content1);
        btnTakePhoto=(Button) findViewById(R.id.makePhotoBtn);
        textView = (TextView) mContentView;



        // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
        mContentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toggle();
            }
        });

        // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
        // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
        // while interacting with the UI.
        findViewById(R.id.makePhotoBtn).setOnTouchListener(mDelayHideTouchListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
        // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
        // are available.
        delayedHide(100);
    }

    private void toggle() {
        if (mVisible) {
            hide();
        } else {
            show();
        }
    }

    private void hide() {
        // Hide UI first
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.hide();
        }
        mControlsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mControlsView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mVisible = false;

        // Schedule a runnable to remove the status and navigation bar after a delay
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mShowPart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHidePart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private void show() {
        // Show the system bar
        mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        mVisible = true;

        // Schedule a runnable to display UI elements after a delay
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHidePart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mShowPart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    /**
     * Schedules a call to hide() in [delay] milliseconds, canceling any
     * previously scheduled calls.
     */
    private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
    }

    public void PhotoClick(View view) {


        saveFullImage();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE) {

            // Проверяем, содержит ли результат маленькую картинку
            if (data != null) {
                if (data.hasExtra("data")) {
                    try {
                        Bitmap thumbnailBitmap = data.getParcelableExtra("data");
                        // TODO Какие-то действия с миниатюрой

                        thumbnailBitmap = RotateBitmap(thumbnailBitmap, 90);
                        mImageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnailBitmap);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        textView.setText("ошибка");
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // TODO Какие-то действия с полноценным изображением,


                try{
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), mOutputFileUri);
                    bitmap = RotateBitmap(bitmap,90);
                    textView.setText(" ");
                    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    textView.setText("ошибка");
                }

                // сохраненным по адресу mOutputFileUri

            }
        }
    }

    public  Bitmap RotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle)
    {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(angle);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }

    private void saveFullImage() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "test.jpg");
        mOutputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mOutputFileUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
    }
}
```

Скажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема, в строке `Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), mOutputFileUri);` или в методе `saveFullImage()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Моих экстрасенсорных способностей хватило только на это:

Скорее всего у вас [FileUriExposedException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUriExposedException.html), лечится применением [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html).

С недавних пор прямое пихание ссылки типа `file://` является некошерным и требуется маскировать ссылку чем-то навроде `content://`, для чего собственно и нужен `FileProvider`